# UITableView and new methods for tvOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, focus, tvos

I am creating a test tvOS app. I have an image (outside the tableview) and when "focused" NOT selected, I would like the image to change... I know that apple has added a couple methods for focus. Could someone tell me which methods I would use to change this image for when it is in "focus"? and how would I use it?
Would I use this method:

```
   - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canFocusRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

or would I use:

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UITableViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
```

Please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: You want to change image when tableViewCell change focus... is that right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change image when `UITableViewCell` item get focus, then you should use second method.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UITableViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
   //You can get focused indexPath like below
   NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [context nextFocusedIndexPath];
   // Now get image from data source, I will assume you have an images array
   UIImage *image = [_imagesArray objectAtIndex:nextIndexPath.row];
   // Set image to image view, assuming you have a property imageView
   _imageView.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used UITableView on tvOS, but it seems that if the item is outside the UITable that it won't be focusable using the table delegate methods.   However, you could extend the UIImageView with a custom class, and then override like:

```
- (void) didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *) context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator
{
    if (context.nextFocusedView == self){
        // change image
        self.image = focusedImage;
    } else {
        // restore view
        self.image = normalImage;
    }

}
- (void)canBecomeFocused
{
    return YES;
}
```

If you run into difficulties navigating to the imageView from the UITableView, you may need to use a UIFocusGuide to bridge the two areas.